# How to plot multiple mean lines in a single histogram with multiple groups present?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, mean

I am plotting a distribution of two variables on a single histogram. I am interested in highlighting each distribution's mean value on that graph through a doted line or something similar (but hopefully something that matches the color present already in the aes section of the code).
How would I do that?

This is my code so far.

```
hist_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x= value, fill= type,  color = type)) +
geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.2) +
labs( x = "Value", y = "Count", fill = "Type", title = "Title") +
guides(color = FALSE)
```

Also, is there any way to show the count of n for each type on this graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've made some reproducible code that might help you with your problem.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate some random data
df <-  data.frame(value = c(runif(50, 0.5, 1), runif(50, 1, 1.5)), 
                  type = c(rep("type1", 50), rep("type2", 50)))

# Calculate means from df
stats <- df %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value),
                                             n = n())

# Make the ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x= value, fill= type,  color = type)) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.2) +
  labs(x = "Value", y = "Count", fill = "Type", title = "Title") +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(data = stats, aes(xintercept = mean, color = type), size = 2) +
  geom_text(data = stats, aes(x = mean, y = max(df$value), label = n), 
            size = 10, 
            color = "black")
```

If things go as intended, you'll end up something akin to the following plot.

[histogram with means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH4U2.png)

Comment: How would you stop the geom_text from overlapping if the means are close to one another?

Comment: I mean physically close, not numeric per say.

Comment: check out the ggrepel package. it should simply be a case of replacing geom_text() with geom_text_repel() 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html

Comment: I did just that and it solved the issue. Thank you!